# Choosing the best assay for my experiment?

Tags: cell-biology, experimental-design, apoptosis, staining, assay-development

Which of the following assays can be used to determine whether cell death specifically due to apoptosis has occurred in a given cell sample? Choose all that apply.

1. WST-1 Assay
2. Caspase Colorimetric Assay
3. Trypan Blue Staining

Which of the following assays can provide direct information about the plasma membrane integrity and/or morphological features of apoptotic cells? Choose all that apply

1. Annexin V-FITC / Propidium Iodide staining.
2. WST-1 Assay
3. Caspase Colorimetric Assay
4. Trypan Blue Staining
5. Wright Staining

My knowledge is very limited with these assays. I know Trypan Blue is used to measure a cell's viability, with dead cells stained blue. Wright Staining is used to study the cell's morphology and makes fragmentation visible. Caspase color and the WST assay seem very similar to me. Both measure cell viability with spectrophotometry.

Comment: Welcome to Biology. Homework-type questions are welcomed, provided OP shows prior efforts to answer the question in the post. Please edit.

Comment: I'm really not provided much information on the assays and the internet is not being very consistent. As far as I know for the first one I believe Trypan Blue Staining is one but im not sure which of the other two could be considered... possibly Caspase colormetric assay? As for the second question i think it is wst and wright staining. Again my knowledge is very limited with these assays. But I would really appreciate clarification or guidance.

Comment: I know trypan is used to measure a cells viability, with dead cells stained blue. wright is used to study the cells morphology and fragmentation is visible with it. caspase color and WST seem very similar to me. Both measure cell viability with spectrophotometry. otherwise i cant differentiate.

Comment: Great additions, please edit this info in the question, as folks may not read the comments. After edits I'm happy to retract my close vote and give you an upvote too :)

Comment: I'm voting to close as homework, despite the editing it still makes very little effort to self help.

Comment: I agree with @rg255. You should at least make an attempt to read what these assays are. "*Caspase color and the WST assay seem very similar to me*": this is not true. Read about them. As it stand it looks exactly like a homework with a very little effort.

Answer (score 0):

Necrotic cells could be trypan blue positive. [WST-1 Assay could reflect cell number by measuring mitochondrial dehydrogenase](http://www.biocompare.com/Product-Reviews/40930-Cell-Proliferation-Reagent-WST-1-From-Roche-Applied-Science/), therefore, you could not know how many cells die in dishes. When you define apoptosis in your experiment as caspase dependent cell death, measuring caspase activity is the best.

PS

Trypan Blue Staining actually is a method to see membrane integrity.